# Фоновая задача. Как реализовать на Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Задача:

1. Забирает из БД исходные данные
2. Формирует, отправляет запрос к  API стороннего сайта и обрабатывает ответ
3. Заносит данные в ДБ

По кнопке все это работает, а вот как сделать процесс фоновым, периодическим и, желательно, асинхронным? 
Пробовал реализовать с помощью `whenever` и `sidekiq`, но не получилось. Задача запускается раз в минуту, но в логах 'sidekiq' ничего нет, выполнение задачи проходит за 0 мс, если смотреть в консоли, да и результатов выполнения задачи не видно. `whenever` и `sidekiq` запущены.

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "UpdateWorker.perform_async"
end
```

**update_worker.rb**

```
    class UpdateWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker
      include CommonMods

      def perform
        logger.info "Things are happening."
        logger.debug "Here's some info: #{hash.inspect}"
        myMethod
      end
      def myMethod
            ....
            ....
            ....
      end
   end
```

Если можно, просветите подробно, как делать.

**UPDATE**
Ларчик просто открывался, нужно было всего лишь сделать рестарт `Sidekiq` после изменений в коде.

Comment: А в основном приложении Sidekiq отрабатывает? Если по запросу дёргать.

Comment: Возможно, у Вас опечатка:
`runner "UpdateWorker.perform" #А у Вас: runner "UpdateWorker.perform_async"`

Comment: @Niki-Timofe Нет, это не опечатка. Sidekiq в методе `perform_async` кладёт набор параметров (включая название класса задачи) в очередь, потом воркер, разгребая очередь, создаёт инстанс задачи и дёргает его `perform`. Так работает Sidekiq.

Comment: @D-side, ой, перепутал с `whenever`

Comment: А то, что метод объявлен после его вызова, это нормально?

Comment: @Niki-Timofe [да, вполне](http://ideone.com/Mv70Fd). Поиск методов происходит уже в рантайме, при объявлении нужна только синтаксическая корректность.

Comment: @D-side Я честно говоря не очень еще разобрался с Sidekiq. Как его по запросу запустить? upd. понял, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @D-side неа `undefined method perform for UpdateWorker:Class` Хотя вроде ж объявлен...

Comment: Вы ж в раннере `perform_async` делаете, его и пробуйте. `perform` действительно не объявлен, как метод **класса**, и **не должен быть**, так что всё ок.

Comment: @D-side да, спасибо. `perform_async` ошибки не вызывает, только где его логи/результаты смотреть я не понимаю. sidekiq.log пустой, хотя в config/sidekiq.yml ':verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:concurrency:  25'

Comment: Та-ак. Кажется, я понял, в чём дело. Вы `sidekiq`-то запустили? :)

Comment: хм... вроде б да.... но, пошел проверять

Comment: @D-side ну просто же sidekiq в терминале и красный пинающийся чувак появляется. или как-то по-другому запускать нужно?

Comment: @nobilik всё так, но по-хорошему, все выполненные для заключения "ничего не делает" действия надо указывать в вопросе. Из неверного расследования запросто можно сделать неверный вывод.

Comment: @D-side я обязательно научусь, как правильно) слегка поправил вопрос

Comment: А зачем сразу и сайдкик и венвер? Это оверхед. Предлагаю оставить что-то одно. Ну и сайдкик перезапускать надо после каждого изменения кода. Это делалось?

Comment: @anoam За рестарт Сайдкика спасибо тебе, мил человек! Все заработало! А вот по поводу, что связка Веневера и Сайдкика это оверхед, если можно подробнее! Одно - расписание, второе - фреймворк для бэкграунд процессов, и в нем нет расписания, разве что в Про версии.

Comment: А ещё можно использовать фоновую [очередь на PostgreSQL](https://github.com/chanks/que), где реализован запуск по расписанию, и им [можно довольно свободно крутить](https://github.com/chanks/que/blob/master/docs/customizing_que.md#recurring-jobs).

Comment: Про `whenever` + `sidekiq`: `sidekiq` тут лишний, запуск вне веб-сервера априори будет вне цикла запрос/ответ.

Comment: @nobilik, просто на практике не нужно и того и другого. Сайдкик используется чтобы отложенно реагировать на действия пользователя. Например конвертировать загруженный файл или сходить во внешнее апи. Просто нельзя браузер заставлять ждать ответ так долго. Веневер уже выполняет задачи в фоне, просто они не привязаны к действиям пользователя. У тебя нет клиента, ждущего ответа, так что время выполнения уходит на второй план. Использовать оба - "каша масляная с маслом".

Comment: @anoam ок, а что будет, если я задам Веневеру запускать выполнение задачи раз в минуту, а он не успеет закончить предыдущее выполнение? Мне по-сути, нужно задачу запускать просто в непрерывном цикле, но параллельно иметь возможность запускать и другие задачи. Я не уверен, что Веневер правильное решение в моем случае.

Comment: @nobilik веневер - обёртка для крона. У него нет своего демона. Вроде он должен запускать задачу даже если та же задача с прошлого раза не остановилась. Но тут я не уверен (никогда не пробовал). Разные задачи он точно даст запустить параллельно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32851/discussion-on-question-by-nobilik------rails).

Comment: Вытащите ваш блок **UPDATE** в отдельный ответ, что ли. А то вопрос считается нерешённым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой случай закрыт благодаря комментарию @anoam. После любых изменений в коде нужно делать рестарт `Sidekiq`. Но дополнительные концептуальные ответы приветствуются!